# TruncatedSVD n_oversamples seems to have no bearing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eigenvector

I'm looking for way to improve the quality of my eigenvectors produced by sklearn TruncatedSVD. The documentation at scikit-learn.org suggests that the n_oversamples parameter is a good place to start. I have a sparse 2200 square matrix as input (provided as three separate files consisting of row indexes, column indexes, and data value.) Here's my code:

```
from array import array
import sys
import numpy as np
import struct
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


path="c:\\users\\lenwh\\documents\\wikipedia\\weights\\"
file=sys.argv[1]
dims=int(sys.argv[2])  #I use 300


with open(path+ file + ".rows","rb") as f:
    rows=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32)


with open(path+ file + ".cols","rb") as f:
    cols=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.int32)

with open(path+ file + ".data","rb") as f:
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)

rowCount=len(np.unique(rows))
csr=csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(rowCount, rowCount))
vectorsfile=path+"eigens.vec"
transfile=path+ file + ".eig"

oversamples=10;
pca=TruncatedSVD(n_components=dims, n_oversamples=oversamples)
pca.fit(csr)
np.savetxt(transfile,pca.transform(csr),fmt='%16f')
```

The problem is that whether I have oversamples set to 10, 100, or 1000, the results are not discernably different, meaning the explained variance is the same for all, as is the performance of the results in my application. As a minimum, I expected that the quality of the explained variance would change. I would appreciate any explanation of where my expectations are misguided, and whether there are any other settings -- or alternatives to TruncatedSVD -- that I could looked to other than the n_components setting.